# Who leaked my source?

Tags: git

Just imagine, having a company with 10 programmers. Each pulling and pushing to the git repository on github or bitbucket.

Then some day, the sourcecode is published on a public website. Is there any technical way to find out who pulled that source that got published?

Is there any way to bind an employee to a specific source, while there multiple employees working on the same source (different local repos)?

Comment: You have a human problem, not a technical problem. Anyway, if the source exists in the repo as posted on said site, then literally anyone with access to the repo could've posted it.

Comment: Imagine that you share a secret between 10 people. Then that secret pops up on a public website. Can you find who leaked it? Highly depends.

Comment: And there are a multitude of ways they could've published it. You would have to get hold of logs from the server and hope they contain information about ip addresses and whatnot of whoever published those files on the server. But in git? No, nothing of the sorts.

Comment: If they published everything (including the .git folder), then they may have an additional remote location set up in .git/logs/refs/remotes which can identify them.  You'd very much have to rely on them making a mistake

Comment: You could *officially* contact the staff at that $public_service and explain the situation. They could in principle help you by analyzing their logs. *But* this would only work if the offender did that from their private Internet connection (i.e. from work). If that was done from your workplace, you'll basically gain nothing unless you also somehow log *all* your traffic which, I think, is an unrealistic expectation. Should that person also do that from any public place (like coffeeshop), the case would be too hard to track also.

Comment: Still, you might try to approach it from another angle: assume that the cause was plain stupidity and not malice. Gather your folks, explain the case, state you think that was a blunder and state whoever did that won't be punished, and offer to either step forward loud and clear or write your a private mail—different people feel differently about "coming out" on blunders. Take action to remove the code from the $public_place.

Comment: All-in-all, this is a question for [IPS](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com); it has nothing to do with Git.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to know who published the code, as Git simply do not store such information (how it would even know who you are? If you mean author data, then it can be simply changed to mention anyone). Git isn't intrusion detection system, so no.

Comment: Pulls aren't logged either IIRC. They might be server-sided (IPs), but Git doesn't have a system for it